# How to express this operator through derivetives?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Imagine a function $f(x)$ which has zero at $x=x_0$.

Now consider the following expression:

$$N[f](x_0)=\frac 1{{\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac 1{f(x_0-h)}+\frac1{f(x_0+h)}}2}}$$

For instance, if $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1/x+1}$$ then $$N[f](0)=1$$

If $$f(x)=\ln(x)$$

then $$N[f](1)=2$$

I wonder, is it possible to express this operator through derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose the function is sufficiently regular near $x$. Taylor series writes:

$$\frac{1}{f(x-h)}+\frac{1}{f(x+h)}=\frac{1}{-f'(x)h+f''(x)h^2/2+O(h^3)}+\frac{1}{f'(x)h+f''(x)h^2/2+O(h^3)}$$

$$=\frac{f'(x)h+f''(x)h^2/2+O(h^3) -f'(x)h+f''(x)h^2/2+O(h^3)}{(f'(x)h+f''(x)h^2/2+O(h^3))(-f'(x)h+f''(x)h^2/2+O(h^3))} $$

$$=-\frac{  f''(x)h^2    +O(h^3)}{(f'(x))^2h^2+ O(h^3) } \to -\frac{  f''(x) }{(f'(x))^2  }.$$
Therefore your operator looks like $$N[f]=-2\frac{(f'(x))^2  }{  f''(x) }.$$

Of course, you need additional hypothesis that $f''(x)\ne 0$. Try to compute your limit for $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=0$.

**EDIT**
The case with $f(x)\ne0$:
$$\frac{1}{f(x-h)}+\frac{1}{f(x+h)}=\frac{1}{f(x)-f'(x)h +O(h^2)}+\frac{1}{f(x)+f'(x)h+O(h^2)}$$
$$=\frac{2f(x)  +O(h^2)}{(f(x)-f'(x)h +O(h^2)) (f(x)+f'(x)h+O(h^2))}\to \frac{2}{f(x)},$$hence $N[f](x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Works! Except in non-pole points it does not give the original function, but this is even better. Also often need to use lomit on the quotinent.

Comment: @Anixx In non-pole points it does not work because in the reasoning we took $f(x)=0$. With $f(x)\ne 0$ we quickly obtain the expected $N[f](x)=f(x)$.

Comment: how would it look like? Sorry, I do not see where u assumed this.

Comment: Can u please write the final result with $f(x)\ne0$ if it is not that difficult?

Comment: Is there a common name for this operator (from your answer)? It seems it is constant for logarithm.

Comment: $$-2\frac {-(f(x))^2-f(x)f''(x)h^2+(f'(x))^2h^2}{2f(x)+f''(x)h^2}$$