# Zeta and Gamma function regularization with $\omega=1/0$

Tags: gamma-function, riemann-zeta, regularization, nonstandard-models

I have recently read about [zeta function regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization), a way of ascribing values to functions having simple poles in a point and to divergent series. The values obtained are the same as those obtained using Ramanujan's summation.

In short this says that a function having pole in $x_0$ should be ascribed the following value:

$$f(x_0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)+f(x_0-h)}2=\lim_{x\to x_0} \left(\frac{f (x)^2 f''\left( x \right)}{2 f'\left(x\right)^2}-f (x)\right)$$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999743/how-to-express-this-operator-through-derivetives/999759) for derivation).

This way we can obtain:

$$1/0=0$$
$$\zeta(1)=\gamma$$
$$\Gamma(0)=-\gamma$$
$$\Gamma(-1)=\gamma-1$$
$$\Gamma(-2)=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{\gamma }{2}$$
$$\Gamma(-3)=\frac{\gamma }{6}-\frac{11}{36}$$
$$\Gamma(-4)=\frac{25}{288}-\frac{\gamma }{24}$$
etc.

But as we can see, these values of Gamma function do not satisfy the functional equation. It seems like every value were missing a non-real term.

We can fix the issue by introducing a value $\omega$ with the following properties:

$$0\, \omega = 1$$
$$\omega+a \ne \omega$$
$$a \omega \ne \omega$$
$$\Re(\omega)=\Im(\omega)=0$$
$$|\omega|=\infty$$

This way the values of the Gamma function at negative arguments will satisfy the functional equation:

$$\Gamma(0)=-\gamma+\omega$$
$$\Gamma(-1)=\gamma-1-\omega$$
$$\Gamma(-2)=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{\gamma }{2}+\frac\omega 2$$
$$\Gamma(-3)=\frac{\gamma }{6}-\frac{11}{36}-\frac\omega 6$$

$$\zeta(1)=\gamma+\omega$$

etc. As you can see, these values perfectly satisfy the functional equation for Gamma.

Thus I wonder

- What algebraic properties of real and complex numbers get lost with introduction of such $\omega$?
- What is the general way of finding the coefficient at $\omega$ for an arbitrary function having a pole (I want an expression in derivatives, similar to the expression for the real part).

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Interesting question.  I don't see the connection between Zeta regularization and your limit, could you provide a reference for that?

Comment: For the $\Gamma$ function, the values are the same as $~\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\Gamma(n+\epsilon)+\Gamma(n-\epsilon)}2$.

Comment: @Antonio Vargas there was a typo in the formula, sorry (actually I inserted the wrong formula).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I wasn't commenting on the formula, I was wondering how it (or the new one) is connected to Zeta regularization.  It's not obvious to me, so I was hoping you could provide a reference.  Your other question doesn't say either.

Comment: @Lucian for Zeta also.

Comment: Didi you notice, that the coefficients at the $\gamma$ and the constant follow the first and second column in the matrix of Stirling numbers 1st kind? (Just adapt the factorial coefficients). Then the set of the constants (with adapted factorials) has $\log(1+x)^2$ as its generating function, and the set of coefficients at the $\gamma$ that of the $\log(1+x)$... The same with the $\omega$: so the sum over all that results for the $\omega$s has then somehow $\log(1+\omega)$  involved (don't know about the significance of this at the moment...)

Comment: I've exercised much with similar questions and think that there is something more general in this. An early discussion of a not too remotely far might be seen here: http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/ProblemWithBellmatrix.pdf . Here I stumbled on a curious discrepancy when summing zetas and which could be explained if one introduces $1/\omega$ into the power series for the $\exp(x)$-function.

Answer (score 1):

Well at least for the second part of the question, each function having pole at $x_0$ can be regularized the following way:

$$f(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)+f(x_0-h)}2+\omega  \lim_{h\to 0}h\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}2 $$

Or at any point,

$$f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)}2+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}2 $$